# Blazor Custom Component Binding

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm just starting to learn Blazor so I'm not that familiar with all the inner workings and I'm just playing around to learn things.  I thought that I would create a simple custom control that combined a  and  into a single control.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <label for="@InputId">@LabelText</label>&nbsp;
    <input id="@InputId" @bind-value="TextValue" @oninput="TextValueChangedCallback" />
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string InputId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string LabelText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string TextValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    private void TextValueChangedCallback(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {
        TextValue = changeEventArgs.Value.ToString();
    }


}
```

In the debugger I can see that TextValue is being updated through the TextValueChangedCallBack.  So that part seems okay.

```
<LabeledTextInput InputId="TestInput" LabelText="Test Label" @bind-TextValue="TestValue"></LabeledTextInput><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" @onclick=OnClickSubmit />

@code
{
    private string TestValue = "nothing";

    private async Task OnClickSubmit()
    {
        await Task.Run(new Action(Submitted));
    } 

    private void Submitted()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(TestValue);
    }
}
```

Now in a page when I use it whether I use @bind-TextValue or just plain TextValue="@TestValue" the value of TestValue never changes from "nothing" to whatever might have been typed in by the user.  I think this has something to do with the way I should be doing the binding between the page and the control.

How can I get TestValue to have the actual value of what was typed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting up the bindings correctly.

These are two ways of addressing your problem: there are more.

1. Here I've set up the bind parameters in the component and tied the element binding in manually.

When you use the element `input` rather than a component `InputText` you need to use `@bind` not `@bind-value`.

```cs
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <label>@LabelText</label>
    <input @bind:get="this.Value" @bind:set="this.SetValue"/>

    @*
    This will update on every keystroke
    <input @bind:get="this.Value" @bind:set="this.SetValue" @bind:event="oninput"/>
    *@
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string LabelText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task SetValue(string? value)
        => await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```

2. You can also achieve the same result by inheriting from one of the Blazor input components.

```cs
@inherits InputText
<div class="">
    <label class="form-label-sm small">@this.Label</label>
    @_baseContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Label { get; set; } = "NotSet";

    // Property to get the render fragment built by the base class
    private RenderFragment _baseContent => builder => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

Here's a demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Input Demo</h1>

<div class="col mb-3">
    <LabelledTextInput @bind-Value=_value Label="Value" class="form-control" />
</div>

<MyTextInput LabelText="Value" @bind-Value=_value />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 mt-4 p-2">
    <pre>Value : @_value</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string? _value;
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement "@bind:get" but I get an error that it can only be used in RazorLanguageVersion 7.0 or higher.  I went to the properties of the project and changed the framework to .NET 7.0 and then unloaded and reloaded the project but that had no effect.  Obviously there is something else that needs to be done.

Comment: It's a VS/SDK error.  The code will compile and run.  It will go away when MS fixes it!